# mysql - summing and differencing two different columns from different table without foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a budget table it has

```
budget_cost, p_id
```

then work package table, it has

```
milewp_cost, p_id
```

both is foreign key to the `p_id` How can I difference that if i just summed them?
I'm working on this code but no luck.

```
select sum(b.milewp_cost) as a, sum(a.budget_cost)b, (a-b) as c
```

EDITED 
`select * from t_budget`

```
t_budget
_________________________
budget_id   budget_amount
1           500
2           600
```

`select * from t_milewp`

```
t_milewp
_________________________
milewp_id   milewp_amount
1           100
2           300
```

`select SUM(budget_amount) as ww from t_budget`

```
ww
__
1100
```

`select SUM(milewp_amount) as ee from t_milewp`

```
ee
__
400
```

From the last two query. How can I join them and subtract them? Nevermind the `p_id` because i'll just gonna use a `where` clause

Comment: Are you looking for one value representing the sum total of all records in the `work_package` table less the sum total of all records in the `budget` table? If so, you should be looking at subqueries. Or for a value for each and every `p_id`, giving the `milewp_cost` less the `budget_cost`? If so, you would need to join the tables on the `p_id`.

Comment: Hi! I just want that the `p_id` is the indicator like. I'll sum all the `budget_cost` and `milewp_cost` with the same `p_id` then difference them.

Comment: That sounds like an unusual schema. Can you edit your question to provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements for each of the tables and also some sample data? If you mention my name (eg @Matt Raines) in a comment when you've done I'll know to look back at the question.

Comment: @MattRaines Okay for example, they are two different tables, no connection to whatsoever. just plain `milewp_id`,`milewp_amount` and `budget_id`,`budget_amount` how can I subtract them after using the `SUM` function then just display it in just 1 row

Comment: I'll need to see the full table structure and ideally some sample data and a desired output for that sample data to be able to help.

Comment: @MattRaines I already edited my answer mister, sorry I'm not good at explaning things, hope my revision is comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is clear what you're trying to achieve so I'll just go with my assumptions.

MySQL doesn't have `FULL JOIN` but you can simulate it by `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t_budget (budget_id int, budget_amount int);
CREATE TABLE t_milewp (milewp_id int, milewp_amount int);

INSERT INTO t_budget VALUES (1, 500), (2, 600);
INSERT INTO t_milewp VALUES (1, 100), (2, 300);
```

Query (for entire table):

```
SELECT SUM(budget_amount) - SUM(milewp_amount)
FROM (
  SELECT tb.budget_id, tm.milewp_id, tb.budget_amount, tm.milewp_amount
  FROM t_budget tb
  LEFT JOIN t_milewp tm
    ON tb.budget_id = tm.milewp_id
  -- add WHERE here if needed (on tb.budget_id)
  UNION 
  SELECT tb.budget_id, tm.milewp_id, tb.budget_amount, tm.milewp_amount
  FROM t_budget tb
  RIGHT JOIN t_milewp tm
    ON tb.budget_id = tm.milewp_id
  -- add WHERE here if needed (on tm.milewp_id)
  ) foo
```

Output:

```
700
```

If you need to limit the ids for computation, add a `WHERE` clause where I left a comment

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9db64c/4)** to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to combine your two queries with subqueries in the select clause:

```
select 
  (select sum(budget_amount) from t_budget)
  -
  (select sum(milewp_amount) from t_milewp)
;
```

And here is another way to achieve the same with subqueries in the join clause:

```
select b.amount - m.amount
from       (select sum(budget_amount) as amount from t_budget) b
cross join (select sum(milewp_amount) as amount from t_milewp) m;
```

If you want results per p_id:

```
select b.p_id, b.amount - m.amount
from (select p_id, sum(budget_amount) as amount from t_budget group by p_id) b
join (select p_ad, sum(milewp_amount) as amount from t_milewp group by p_id) m
  on m.p_id = b.p_id;
```

But this only works if every p_id has an entry in both tables. Otherwise you'd need the appropriate outer join - maybe a full outer join even which you'd have to simulate as MySQL doesn't feature it.